# React state changing on change copy of original state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a simple game like purple pairs in Purple palace game using React. I have a method named `clickBtn`, it is supposed to increment the count on click and decrement on second click but I don't know why the `handleClick` method is changing `chosen` and `clicked` property of state even if a copy of the new state is made without using `setState` method. Can you help me fix this?

```js
class GameBoard extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      score: 0,
      time: 0,
      list: [...generateObList(), ...generateObList()],
      count: 0
    };
  }

  handleClick = (id) => {
    this.clickBtn(id);
    const list = this.state.list.slice();
    const current = list.find((a) => a.id === id);
    for (let x of list) {
      if (x.clicked && x.value == list.find((a) => a.id == id).value) {
        x.chosen = true;
        x.clicked = false;
        current.chosen = true;
        current.clicked = false;
        // this.setState((prev) => ({
        //   list: prev.list.map((el) =>
        //     el.id === id ? current : el.value === current.value ? x : el
        //   ),
        //   score: prev.score + 1
        // }));
      }
    }
  };

  clickBtn = (id) => {
    const current = this.state.list.slice().find((e) => e.id === id);
    let deClick = current.clicked;
    current.clicked = !current.clicked;
    console.log(current);
    this.setState(
      (prev) => ({
        list: prev.list.map((el) => (el.id === id ? current : el)),
        count: prev.count + (deClick ? -1 : 1)
      }),
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.count, deClick, current);
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    const boardStyle = {
      gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(5, 1fr)`,
      gridTemplateRows: `repeat(5,1r)`
    };
    let list = this.state.list.map((n) => (
      <Card
        value={n.value}
        onClick={(e) => {
          this.handleClick(n.id);
        }}
        show={!n.chosen}
      />
    ));
    return (
      <div class="gameBoard" style={boardStyle}>
        {list}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`slice()` just return a shallow copy of the array so both original and copy refer to the same array items if the items are reference type ( objects ).

> For object slice copies object references into the new array. Both the
> original and new array refer to the same object. If a object changes,
> the changes are visible to both the new and original arrays.

Try to deep copy the objects. You can easily do deep copy by using, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr))`

Also you can try `lodash`'s `cloneDeep()` method.

For more details about deep cloning - https://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/11306028

Comment: "Easily do deep copy" comes with a lot of caveats. That approach will not properly handle nested references to objects, or instantiated classes like `Date`, to name a few. It may work if you have very simple data constructs with literal string and number values, but be careful.

Also, you ought to mention that updating React state directly is a terrible, terrible idea and an anti-pattern. `setState()` should ALWAYS be used to update state.

Comment: Yes. That's why I also mention about `cloneDeep` & added reference to a detailed answer about deep copying. And also, because he do the shallow copy, he  update the state directly. If he did the deep copy the variable, `current` then it should work as he use `setState` to update it.

Comment: I wanted to mention that I tried using `rest` operator because I wanted to use a copy of the state in another component. It didn't work but when I used the `JSON parse`  mentioned in the answer it worked. The object had nested objects but not more than 2 levels. I was shocked that the rest didn't work. JSON will not make good copies with null, undefined and function / property values